# Description of the equalizer of $\prod _j R/I_j \rightrightarrows \prod _{i,j}R/(I_i+I_j)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem, affine-schemes

This will hopefully be my last question about the chinese remainder theorem. I have [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565916/sheafyness-and-relative-chinese-remainder-theorem) [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553900/multi-pullbacks-and-the-relative-chinese-remainder-theorem?lq=1) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553430/relative-chinese-remainder-theorem-and-the-lattice-of-ideals) in an attmept to get a general version without conditions on the ideals which will trivially imply the usual version if they are assumed comaximal.

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597245/chinese-remainder-theorem-as-sheaf-condition/1601660#1601660) prompts me to ask what is the equalizer of the natural arrows below, sending $(r_j+I_j)_j$ to $(r_j+I_j+I_i)_{i,j}$ and $(r_i+I_i+I_j)_{i,j}$:
$$\prod _j R/I_j \rightrightarrows \prod _{i,j}R/(I_i+I_j)$$
The elegant example given there shows the equalizer is not generally $R/\bigcap_j I_j$, but I'm having trouble figuring out what it is. I'm familiar with only the most basic definitions about affine schemes.

Comment: I don't think there's really any simpler description than "the equalizer of that diagram".